# Login fails with user from data migration

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

I try to add a new user with help of data migration (django 1.6.7 + south). My migration:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        user = User(
            pk=1, 
            username="admin", 
            password="admin",
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=True,
            is_staff=True,
            last_login="2011-09-01T13:20:30+03:00", 
            email="email@gmail.com",
            date_joined="2011-09-01T13:20:30+03:00"
        )
        user.save()

    def backwards(self, orm):
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot reverse this migration.")
```

User creation works as I'm able to obtain the user instance via the shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> user.username
u'admin'
>>> user.password
u'admin'
```

The problem is when I'm trying to authorise via the admin panel, there is an error:

> Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a password in this way for a `User` object (i.e. `password="admin"`). When Django authenticates a user it hashes the password you enter in the admin login screen using your `settings.SECRET_KEY`. When Django attempts to match this hash against your stored password, it is matching against the string `'admin'`.

You need to update your migration to look like the following:

```
    user = User(pk=1, username="admin", is_active=True,
                is_superuser=True, is_staff=True,
                last_login="2011-09-01T13:20:30+03:00"
                email="email@gmail.com",
                date_joined="2011-09-01T13:20:30+03:00")
    user.set_password('admin')
    user.save()
```

Note the removal of the `password='admin'` and the addition of the useful `User` model method `set_password`

HTH

Comment: Can I in some way add the user_permissions?

Comment: You can but you will need to do this after user.save() e.g. from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, permissions = Permission.objects.filter(id__in=[your_ids]), user.user_permissions.add(*permissions) (or something similar). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization for more detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `user.set_password()`, as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26658015), fails in my data-migration (django 2.1) with the following error:

`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'set_password'`

A similar issue is discussed in [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26445#comment:2). As suggested there, you can use `make_password()` instead (also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def create_user(app_registry, schema_editor):
    user_model = app_registry.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    user_model.objects.create(username='a. user',
                              email='a.user@email.com',
                              password=make_password('areallystrongpassword'))
```